# ActiveRecord validtaes_format_of doesn't get excuted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

There's Person class and PersonName class in AR, with has_many relationship. Now I want to validate the format of the PersonName model to be either alphabetic or space. Here is the code:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :names, :class_name => "PersonName", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :names
end

class PersonName < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  attr_accessible :full, :first, :middle, :last, :maiden, :title, :suffix, :nick
  validates_format_of :full, :first, :middle, :last, :maiden, :title, :suffix, :nick, :with => /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/, :on => :save
end
```

Seems the validates_format not get executed. When I run

```
PersonName.create(:full => '@#$@').valid?
```

in the console, it returns true. I tried to change it to be :on => :create but it still return true. What could be the problem? Do I need to specify something in the Person class?

Comment: Try `PersonName.new(:full => '@#$#').valid?`. Does that still return `true`?

Comment: yes, it still return true.

Answer (score 0):

From rails documentation

```
Note: use \A and \Z to match the start and end of the string, ^ and $ match the start/end of a line
```

I think that is your problem

Comment: It's `\z` (with a lowercase 'z').

Comment: thanks for the hint, I think you are right (/A and /z for string) but /\A[a-zA-Z\s\.]*\z/ doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, should use create! instead of create.